# Running "vue ui" on Windows Subsystem For Linux (WSL) will not work

Tags: vue.js

An error will get generated when running:

```
vue ui
```

```
vue ui
  Starting GUI...
  Ready on http://localhost:8001
events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd.exe',
  path: 'cmd.exe',
  spawnargs: [ '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', 'http://localhost:8001' ]
}
```

Expected to get an app running on port localhost:8001, but the above error gets generated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because it is trying to open a browser window from inside WSL terminal.

Instead, do the following:

```
vue ui --headless
```

This will avoid running the cmd.exe to open a browser and instead run the app on port 8001. You'll have to open a browser manually to http://localhost:8001